# Rectangle-Cylindrical Enclosure ideas?

Tags: plastic

Sadly SE doesn’t really have a great fit subsite for my specific question, and the DIY stack exchange is mainly for home improvement. Thus, I post here.

I have designed a usb device and ordered and assembled the circuit boards. This looks ugly, and I would like to make an enclosure for it. DIY electronics enclosures are dinky, ugly and too big. I want a professional look. Sadly, I do not have an assembly agreement with a plastics factory. If I did, I would have a custom enclosure poured with sleek, black plastic. Instead, I will have to make the enclosure DIY before pitching the product to potential sponsors. My entire design could fit inside the USB plug shown below.

[image]
Credit: Amazon

Ignore the male plug, my design will has only female plugs. I want an enclosure for my device with very similar style and dimensions as what is pictured above, only black plastic instead of silver.

I have thought of using some kind of specialized pipe and cutting the ends. I have also thought about pouring the enclosure in epoxy but that would just be a mess. I have tic-tac containers I could spray paint but that seems a little less professional than I would like. Are there any opaque containers that could achieve such a look?

Comment: Hi Judson, do you have a picture of the circuit boards, and can you provide the dimensions?

Answer (score 5):

As your objective appears to be the requirement to present a product, you aren't asking for production methods. This suggests that a suitable method is to use 3D printing, specifically resin printing, to create the enclosure.

3D resin printing is nearly layer free (strong magnification required) and presents a smooth professional appearance. It can be painted to provide the necessary coloration.

You'd be able to have an enclosure designed specifically for the components to be placed within, providing structural support for circuit boards, switches, LEDs, etc.

Online services such as Shapeways will create these prototypes or you may find local resources. A nearby makerspace would also be a resource.

Another alternative is to create a plug/mold/part system. Carve, cut, sand or otherwise create a duplicate of your design in any convenient material. Even balsa wood serves the purpose as long as the surface is sealed.

Pour molding silicone around the plug and when cured, remove it and pour resin to create your final component. Resin can be colored as required, rather than to resort to applying paint.

The above is a summary, as the process is slightly more involved than described, but is an option for you to have a reasonably professional appearing enclosure. Considerations involve resin pour path and venting, mold parting and alignment, etc. Additional research is recommended if this is your selection.